# how to get name of all file in a directory and sub-directory in java

Tags: java, file, file-io, directory-structure

I have a directory which consist of some different sub directory which every one have several files. how can i get name of all file?

Comment: What have you tried? If you look at `java.io`, it should be fairly straightforward code. You'll need a recursive-descent function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use a library, try the [listFiles](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20boolean%29) method from apache commons io [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html), which will recurse into directories for you.

Here's an example of how you could call it to find all files named `*.dat` and `*.txt` in any directory anywhere under the specified starting directory:

```
Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(new File("my/dir/path"), {"dat", "txt"}, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void walkin(File dir) {
                String pattern = "file pattern"; //for example ".java"

                File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
                if(listFile != null) {
                        for(int i=0; i<listFile.length; i++) {
                                if(listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                                        walkin(listFile[i]);
                                } else {
                                        if(listFile[i].getName().endsWith(pattern))
                                        {
                                                System.out.println(listFile[i].getPath());
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Recurse through the directory structure, gathering the names of all the files that are not sub-directories.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for File.list() take a closer look into the javadoc for more details.

Answer (score 1):

To list a directory using Java do something similar to this

```
File dir = new File(fname);
String[] list = dir.list();

if(list == null){
  System.out.println("Specified directory does not exist or is not a directory.");
  System.exit(0);
}else{
  //list the directory content
  for(int i = 0; i < chld.length; i++){
  String fileName = list[i];
  System.out.println(fileName);
}
```

Most of this code comes from here, http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/DirectoryListing.shtml

Answer (score 1):

This programme will display the whole structure with nested files and nested sub directories with file system.

```
import java.io.File; 
  
public class DirectoryStructure  
{ 
     static void RecursivePrint(File[] arr, int index, int level)  
     { 
         // terminate condition 
         if (index == arr.length) {
             return;
         }
           
         // tabs for internal levels 
         for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
             System.out.print("\t");
         }
           
         // for files 
         if (arr[index].isFile()) {
             System.out.println(arr[index].getName());
         }
           
         // for sub-directories 
         else if (arr[index].isDirectory()) 
         { 
             System.out.println("[" + arr[index].getName() + "]"); 
               
             // recursion for sub-directories 
             RecursivePrint(arr[index].listFiles(), 0, level + 1); 
         } 
            
         // recursion for main directory 
         RecursivePrint(arr, ++index, level); 
    } 
      
    // Driver Method 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        // Provide full path for directory(change accordingly)   
        String maindirpath = "E:\\dms\\Notes"; 
                  
        // File object 
        File maindir = new File(maindirpath); 
           
        if (maindir.exists() && maindir.isDirectory()) 
        { 
            // array for files and sub-directories  
            // of directory pointed by maindir 
            File arr[] = maindir.listFiles(); 
              
            System.out.println("**********************************************"); 
            System.out.println("Files from main directory : " + maindir); 
            System.out.println("**********************************************"); 
              
            // Calling recursive method 
            RecursivePrint(arr, 0, 0);  
       }  
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Apache Commons**

```
String filePath = "/apps/fraud";
String[] acceptedExtension = {"ctl","otl","dat","csv","xls"};
String[] acceptedFolders = {"suresh","dir","kernel"};

Collection fileList =  FileUtils.listFiles(
                 new File(filePath), 
                 new SuffixFileFilter(acceptedExtension) ,
                 new NameFileFilter(acceptedFolders) 
                );
```